# Protect the downloaded content from Android

Tags: android, security, pdf

Am developing an offline pdf reader, which will download pdf files from remote and store inside the directory(say Android->data->com.example.test) and it will be shown in my app and i can read both in online and offline.

My issue is, If I open any PDFViewers like Adobe,Radaee viewers I can see my PDF's.

How can i avoid this. I dont want to show them in other apps.

This is not intended behaviour. we can control. Am looking for solution.

**Example** : Whatsapp's media like albums,profilepictures will be stored in device. We can view it. If you open any external Imageviewers we cant see the Profile Pictures. We can see the Media files. But Profile pics will be hidden. I need the exact solution.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Imran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the PDF on [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You are presently storing the PDF on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: And for rooted devices?!